# Changes to file in a git feature-branch were applied to the file after reverting to master branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm so confused right now. I don't know if this was a bug in GIT or PHPSTORM and I honestly don't expect anyone to have an answer because in all of my years using Git and PhpStorm I have *NEVER* seen something like this happen. The questing being what actually happened, why, and which piece of software is responsible for the issue?

I am working on a massive search system update for one of my sites. The main "search results" file has been completely overhauled in this new branch. Last night, I committed all changes to the working branch and pushed them up to the server and left the (clean) branch checked out. This morning a request came in to make a change to the live site (which that code is reflected by the master branch) so I needed to checkout back to master to perform the update.

When I did `git checkout master` the "search results" script was still open in my editor and I noticed that the tab was blue (pending updates) and almost every line in the file was flagged as "changed" in the editor. Upon closer inspection I could tell the file still had all of the contents that the file had been updated to in the new feature branch that I had just committed, pushed and checked out from.

I literally had to do `git restore path/to/file` to restore it to the version of the file it was supposed to be for the branch I just checked out to.

The contents of file was at no point copied to my clipboard so there is absolutely no way I could have accidentally pasted the updated file over the old one.

My best guess is that PhpStorm somehow glitched out due to the file being open when I checked out to the master branch (which I do all the time without issue), and somehow restored the contents of the file after the checkout command changed the data on the disk / filesystem.

Here is a copy of my CLI I/O when this occurred:

```
$ git push
Enumerating objects: 57, done.
Counting objects: 100% (57/57), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 4.58 KiB | 2.29 MiB/s, done.
Total 29 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To ssh://[redacted]/home/[redacted]
1087b188..c3dc079d  search-update -> search-update
```

The above was me pushing the fully committed update branch to the server last night. Below this is where I picked up this morning:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

-- Here is where I noticed the file flagged as updated with the wrong contents --

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   path/to/file.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

So I manually restored the file:

```
$ git restore path/to/file.php

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I will post this as bug/issue to the respective issue trackers (PhpStorm / Git) but I also wanted to post it here in a neutral space since I don't who's at fault here and one might blame the other and also, I have absolutely no clue how to "replicate" the issue as I've literally never seen anything like this before in my life.

Comment: Do you have an actual question, or have you already resolved this problem yourself?

Comment: Not resolved. The question is what actually happened, why and which piece of software is responsible for the issue?

Comment: Edit your otherwise well written question and make it a question from the start +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen out of mad respect for your staggering amount of site reputation I will oblige :)

Comment: Suppose after committing the script on the new branch, in the editor you bumped the space bar and the file was sitting there ready for you to save it. Many editors will just wait  even if the original version of the file changes out from under it. Then when you go back in your editor, if you save that file (or if it auto-saves), now Git can see it as a pending change. I doubt this is what happened because it would require you to accidentally leave the file edited, and then also not notice it got saved from within the editor after the branch switch. Maybe something similar though?

Comment: @TTT - The contents of the file was completely reverted to the state it was in pre-checkout. This isnt the case of there was just a random space or the file was marked as changed because of an accidental keystroke. The entire contents of the file was wrong / changed / updated. The only way I could have "accidentally caused this" would be if I had the update branch version copied to my clip board, then somehow accidentally selected all and pasted and there is no way that happed as I never had the contents of the file copied to my clipboard.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't even need an edit. The file is open in the editor with the new version. You switch to `master`. The editor detects the file changed, and perhaps prompt with "This file has changed do you wish to reload it?" But you don't reload it, and then (somehow) the file gets saved again with what's in the editor. So maybe there's only one thing that needed to happen. Editor saved the in-memory copy either with or without your permission.

Comment: Since the checkout was done from CLI, what could have happened is indeed something going out of sync between IDE and file system, but a prompt (Memory vs On-disk conflict) should have appeared in this case. I am afraid this is quite imposible to investigate if it was s single time occurence, as defautl log level is not enough.

Comment: @DmitriySmirnov I recognize your name from the JetBrains tracker so I'm assuming you saw I posted this there too. I am thinking that it might have been possible that I somehow fat-fingered ctrl+z or otherwise caused an undo operation within the open file and somehow accepted the "reload from disk" confirmation prompt. I tested this series of actions and the end result was the same as I experienced. I have no idea how I could have done all of that without realizing it but I wouldn't put it outside the realm of possibility. If this is a bug though its pretty concerning so thats why I posted.